# How do you disable a service in systemd?

Tags: systemd, services

I know what the command is `sytemctl disable NAME` but I have a question about the `NAME` parameter.

**For example the `bluetooth` service[1] on Fedora 21. For the `NAME` parameter should you put `bluetooth` or `bluetooth.service` or `bluetooth.target`?**

Please note I am using bluetooth as an example but the question is meant to be generic (i.e. if a service has many associated units (i.e. socket, target, service)).

---

[1] When I searched for the bluetooth service I found a couple things that matched the "bluetooth" grep string:

```
$ systemctl list-unit-files|grep -i bluetooth
bluetooth.service                           enabled 
bluetooth.target                            static
```

Comment: +1, and following this because I'd like to know if there's a simple way to disable services that have restarting dependencies (ala [cups](https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/11012/how-to-stop-cupsd/))

Answer (score 5):

Services are defined in unit files that have a `.service` suffix.

When using `systemctl` to disable a service specifically, you should specify the full name of the unit file (e.g. `bluetooth.service`). If you omit the `.service` suffix, then `.service` is assumed. So, for example, the following two commands are equivalent:

With an explicit `.service` suffix:

```
$ systemctl disable bluetooth.service
```

With an implicit `.service` suffix:

```
$ systemctl disable bluetooth
```

Regarding the `bluetooth.target` file: the concept of SysV Init Runlevels has been replaced with *targets* in `systemd`. You should refer to [man systemd.target](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.target.html) for more information.